# C# Model binding complex property

Tags: c#, system.web.http

In my REST API, my model binding is not mapping a property that is a list of objects.  It correctly gets to the controller, and shows all the properties but they are empty.

E.g. for the POST request `{age: 202, setting: ["school"]}` I get something like this in the response:

```
Got param type=SearchStringDTO; param={"age":202,"setting":[]}
```

I want it to respond with something like this:

```
Got param type=SearchStringDTO; param={"age":202,"setting":["school":true, "hospital":false]}
```

**How can I guide it to parse the setting parameter into a `List<Setting>` ?**

Here is the controller:

```cs
using System.Web.Http;
...
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Index(SearchStringDTO param) {
            return ResponseMessage(this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Got param type= " + param.GetType() + "; param = " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param)));

        }
```

Here is the model:

```cs
    public sealed class SearchStringDTO {
        public int age { get; set; }

        public List<Setting> setting { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the Setting class:

```cs
    public class Setting {
        public bool hospital { get; set; }
        public bool school { get; set; }
    }
```

I started down this path to parse things out manually, but it's a nightmare of JObject, JToken, JArray stuff.

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Index(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject param) {
            return ResponseMessage(this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Got param type= " + param.GetType() + "; param = " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param)));
        }
```

Maybe I need a custom bind model? I got lost trying to figure out how to build and use one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok, but your json input parameter is not in a correct format. I tested

```
[HttpPost]
public string Index( [FromBody] SearchStringDTO param)
{
return "Got param type= " + param.GetType()
 + "; param = " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param);
}
```

in postman using:

```
 {age: 202, setting: [{"school":false, "hospital":true},{"school":true, "hospital":false}]}
```

and got output :

```
Got param type= SearchStringDTO; param = {"age":202,"setting":[{"hospital":true,"school":false},{"hospital":false,"school":true}]}
```